# Rails inherits subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this three classes user, driver, company.
every company or driver belongs a user. The models look like

```
 class Company < User
  has_many :driver
 end

 class Driver < User
 end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:admin, :support, :B2B , :B2C]
 end
```

and the database looks like

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email

  t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :companies do |t|
   t.string :comp_name
   t.string :first_name_counterpart
   t.string :last_name_counterpart
   t.string :iban_nr
   t.string :bic
   t.string :email_counterpart
   t.string :addresse
   t.string :city
   t.string :zip

   t.references :user  
   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end

class CreateDrivers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :drivers do |t|
   t.string :first_name
   t.string :last_name
   t.date :birthday
   t.integer :sex
   t.integer :dpi
   t.integer :score


   t.references :user
   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

Why can't I create a Driver-instance. For example, if I try `d = Driver.new`, I get a user-instance.`d = Driver.new
=> #<Driver id: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Answer (score 1):

This is how Rails guesses the table name from the model classes. Quoting from the [ActiveRecord docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) for `table_name`:

> Guesses the table name (in forced lower-case) based on the name of the class in the inheritance hierarchy **descending directly from `ActiveRecord::Base`**. So if the hierarchy looks like: `Reply < Message < ActiveRecord::Base`, then `Message` is used to guess the table name even when called on `Reply`.

You should be able to force the proper table name by the `table_name=` setter, e.g.:

```
class Driver < User
  self.table_name = "drivers"
end
```

On the other hand, I am also not sure that your approach (with such inheritance) will not cause problems somewhere else.

Comment: I am confused . I want to store every company and driver at the same time in User. I mean when I create a Driver should automatically  create a user with email and password. please correct me if I am wrong!
but when I create a driver in console, get nil as Answer for `User.all` just nil

Comment: Aha, I don't think that Rails works that way. What you wrote in the comment above, resembles collections (e.g. has_many, belongs_to) but actually this is not the case as, if I get it correctly, a Driver is the same object as User, only with some functionality beyond User. So it's not like "a Driver also has/belongs to a User". In that case I think the STI approach is actually what you're after, see the answer by @Dharam.

Answer (score 1):

If you have models with inheritance like you do:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:admin, :support, :B2B , :B2C]
end

class Company < User
  has_many :driver
end

class Driver < User
end
```

`rails` infers that you are after Single Table Inheritance (STI) and expects there is just a base table `users` with a column `type` which stores the records of `User`, `Company` and `Driver` with actual class name (ex: `Company` or `Driver` etc).

If you would rather want to have separate tables `users`, `companies` and `drivers` because each of those tables have different set of columns, and the only reason why you are put inheritance in place is to share some common functionality, then you should extract the common functionality into `modules` and mix them into those models (by just inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

`rails`, through `active_support` provides whats called `concerns` to extract the common functionality into modules and mix them intuitively.

You could probably get away with inheritance and still have these models point to separate tables with the declaration of `self.table_name = "table_name"`. But it is not a good idea, as it goes around the `rails` conventions and may cause problems down the lane.

Refer to [ActiveRecord::Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) and [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) for more info.

Comment: Do you mean, if I create a new instance of Driver, this will be stored in User?